# A problem in number of prime factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$ $$^kn = n^{n^{n^{.^{.^{.^{.^{n}}}}}}}(k\space\text{times})$$

with $^0n = 1$.

> Let $$S_n= {}^nn + {}^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}n + {}^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}\right\rfloor}n + \dots + 1$$
>
> Here in $S_n$, $n$ appears only once. So, for example $S_3=3^{3^3}+3+1$, $S_4=4^{4^{4^4}}+4^4+4+1$, $S_5=5^{5^{5^{5^5}}}+5^5+5+1$, etc.
>
> Show that for infinitely many values of $n$, number of prime factors of $S_n$ is less than $n$.

I checked  $n=2$ and $n=3$: $S_2=7$ and $S_3=7625597484991=223\times 34195504417$.

I don't know how to start actually. My teacher(who gave me this problem) did not give any hint. Can anyone help me here?

Also see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278943/a-problem-in-number-of-prime-factors)

Comment: $n \uparrow \uparrow k$?

Comment: @KennyLau I know the notation something like `suffix k then n`, is this also notation for that?

Comment: @D1AmZUasumU Yes $^kn$ is also a notation for this operation.

Comment: Do you think your teacher knows how to prove the claim?

Comment: Note that the examples (presumably provided by your teacher) conveniently stopped at $n=3$. $S_4$ is well defined, but you'll never find it -- it's way too big to compute.

Comment: @quasi I dont think that to prove the claim it is needed to compute the actual values, all that is asked for is some sort of construction.

Comment: @D1AmZUa sumU: I would forget the problem. In my view, it's intractable. But if your teacher supplies a proof, please post it here.

Comment: @D1AmZUa sumU: What is the title of the course? What level?

Comment: @quasi just reading number theory, I think he gave me this problem because of my curiosity in prime factors. May be it is a hard problem.

Comment: @D1AmZUa sumU: It's beyond hard. I doubt your teacher can prove it.

Comment: @quasi  I think you are right. I am just wasting my time.